# Josephus Variant

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I set myself the challenge of trying to solve a variant of the josephus problem where instead of killing every second person, every third person dies. The formula for the original sequence is   $$2(n-2^ \left.\lfloor log_2 (n)\rfloor \right.) +1 $$
i have created a python 2.7 script to find theaters which i will add a link to later. I believe it is non-polynomal. Anyway, the first twenty terms are: 1,1,1,4, 3, 6, 4, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9, 12, 12, 1, 4, 7, 7, 10, 13

**Edit**
Just to avoid ambiguity, the killing will continue in a circle fashion until there is only one person left

**Python Script**

```
print "Josephus Problem"

#create and populate array
while True:
    a = []
    counter = 1
    limit = int(raw_input('enter limit'))

    while counter <= limit:
        a.append(counter)
        counter += 1

    #start main program loop
    counter = 1
    jump = 3 #size of jumps
    position = 1 #starting position 2nd index
    while counter < limit: #go around limit-1 times
        popped = a.pop(position) #remove from array
        print str(popped) + " removed"
        position += jump - 1
        if position >= len(a):
            position = position % len(a)

        counter += 1

    print "The remaining value is: " + str(a[0]) #print remaining array value
    print '1: again'
    print '2: exit'
    reply = raw_input('would you like to go again')
    if reply == 2:
        break
```

Comment: I doubt you will find a nice rule.  Taking out $1/3$ of the numbers leaves a difficult ambiguity on where you start the next round.  The series isn't in OEIS-you might want to add it.

Comment: I hope my edit answers this for you

Comment: I didn't mean your problem statement was ambiguous.  I just meant that it is not obvious (at least to me) how to incorporate the value of $n \pmod 3$ into your calculation and that makes a closed form harder.

Comment: ok i understand

Comment: @Ross Millikan the original problem was take the first digit to the end in base 2 but it doesen't work with this problem

Comment: You might want to check your results against http://oeis.org/A032434.

Comment: This case (as well as the "skipping $n$ people" variant) is discussed in Knuth's *Concrete Mathematics*, along with a reasonably nice closed form.

Comment: What is the question?